# Python/Pandas: How do I use FuzzyWuzzy to replace typos in a column with names of countries?

Tags: python, pandas, replace, fuzzywuzzy

I have a data frame with around 500K rows that contain a column called `country`, among other stuff. My goal is to replace all those possible values where the entry for the `country` column had different typos.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
# Starting dataset:
d = {'country': ['Unites Sates', 'United state','Cnda','canada','United State', 'United sates of America','Mexio','mexico','Mejico','America','U.S.A.','UsA of A','cAnada','u. s. a. ','United States of America']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

                     country
0               Unites Sates #wants to replace
1               United state #wants to replace
2                       Cnda #wants to replace
3                     canada #wants to replace
4               United State #wants to replace
5    United sates of America #wants to replace
6                      Mexio #wants to replace
7                     Mexico #wants to replace
8                     Mejico #wants to replace
9                    America #wants to replace
10                    U.S.A. #wants to replace
11                  UsA of A #wants to replace
12                    cAnada #wants to replace
13                 u. s. a.  #wants to replace
14  United States of America


# Expected Outcome:
d = {'country': ['United States of America','United States of America','Canada','Canada','United States of America','United States of America','Mexico','Mexico','Mexico', 'United States of America','United States of America','United States of America','Canada','United States of America','United States of America']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

                     country
0   United States of America #replaced
1   United States of America #replaced
2                     Canada #replaced
3                     Canada #replaced
4   United States of America #replaced
5   United States of America #replaced
6                     Mexico #replaced
7                     Mexico #replaced
8                     Mexico #replaced
9   United States of America #replaced
10  United States of America #replaced
11  United States of America #replaced
12                    Canada #replaced
13  United States of America #replaced
14  United States of America
```

One of the things I tried was to create a list called `correct_countries_df` containing the correct country names and use it as:

```
df['country_BestMatch'] = df['country'].map(lambda x: process.extractOne(x, correct_countries_df['country'])[0])
```

but it seems that I'm not able to do that.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If your `correct_countries_df` looks like:

```
>>> correct_countries_df

                    country
0  United States of America
1                    Canada
2                    Mexico
```

Then, your code is right

```
>>> df['country'].map(lambda x: process.extractOne(x, correct_countries_df['country'])[0])

0     United States of America
1     United States of America
2                       Canada
3                       Canada
4     United States of America
5     United States of America
6                       Mexico
7                       Mexico
8                       Mexico
9     United States of America
10    United States of America
11    United States of America
12                      Canada
13    United States of America
14    United States of America
Name: country, dtype: object
```